# Update global variable in event function in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, variables, loops, scope

I think this question has been asked before but i was unable to find an answer, maybe I'm lacking the good words to describe my problem.

I have a loop in which, each iteration i create an object and I add an event listener which callback function uses the created object.

```
for(var i in items)
{
    x = new SomeClass(i)

    someAPI.event.addListener(i, 'click', function(ev){
        x.someMethod()
    }); 
}
```

What happens, and I understand why, is the variable `x` within the event function definition is evaluated only when the event is triggered, and `x` is equals to the last value that has been affected to this name, which is the value given at the last iteration.

I would like to know how is it possible to get the wanted behavior, which is getting the current value of `x` in the loop, within the event function definition.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(var i in items) {
    (function(j) {
        var x = new SomeClass(j);

        someAPI.event.addListener(j, 'click', function(ev){
            x.someMethod()
        });
    })(i);
}
```

The key is the `var` keyword, creating a new instance of the class on each iteration.
I added the IIFE to keep the value of `i` constant and to create a new scope on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. Actually, i used the `var` keyword in my code (was missing in my code example), but what was missing in my code was the IIFE.